# SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided when trying to access US Census Tigerline Shapefiles FTP server

Tags: ruby, ftp

Trying to browse the US Census Department's Tigerline Shapefiles API and not getting any luck. Here's what I've tried:

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp = Net::FTP.new("ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/BG/2010")
SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:228:in `initialize'
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:228:in `open'
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:228:in `block in open_socket'
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:223:in `open_socket'
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:248:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:247:in `connect'
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:160:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/daviddouglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

This is an open FTP server that I can access with my browser and other tools. I can even directly reference specific file URL's on this server and download them successfully with `open-uri`. The FTP URL listed above however throws a bit of a curveball and displays a bunch of unexpected URL's, so I have to browse it and return a list of filenames to go forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initialize` method of the `Net::FTP` class expects a hostname (or IP) as its argument, not an FTP URL. Following the [examples from the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html), this should work instead:

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('ftp2.census.gov')
ftp.login
files = ftp.list('/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/BG/2010')
# => file listing of the directory
```

Please see [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html) for the `Net::FTP` class for details on how to access remote files and directories.